# Why doesn't 'AND NOT (value.title IN ['item1','item2']' return the correct result in anormcypher but works in the neo4j console?

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher, anormcypher

Anormcypher 0.80, Scala 2.11.7

I'm attempting to exclude a list of items from a cypher result set by using 'AND NOT (value.title IN ['item1','item2']'.

The cypher query I'm running works in the neo4j console but does not exlcude item1 and item2 when I try to execute the same query using anormcypher. the query is as follows:

```
MATCH (c:Item)-[:INCLUDES_TERM]-(t:Term),(b:Box)-[:CONTAINS_TERM]-(t), 
 (b)-[r:IS_ABOUT_THING]-(thm:Thing) 
 where c.name = 'aName'
 AND NOT (thm.title IN [('item1','item2')]) 
 AND b.date >= 1443657600000 AND b.date <= 1443657700000 
 return DISTINCT(thm.title) as thing, count(b) as amount 
 order by amount desc  LIMIT 50
```

In the neo4j console this cypher query will return a result with item1 and item2 filtered out.

If I run the query from scala using anormcypher, item1 and item2 will not be filtered out of the result. This is the code:

```
val exclusions:String = "'item1','item2'"
val name = "aName"
val startDate = "1443657600000"
val endDate = "1443657700000"
val cypherQuery = Cypher("""MATCH (c:Item)-[:INCLUDES_TERM]-(t:Term),(b:Box)-[:CONTAINS_TERM]-(t), 
   (b)-[r:IS_ABOUT_THING]-(thm:Thing) 
   where c.name = {item} 
   AND NOT (thm.title IN [{exclusions}]) 
   AND b.date >= {startDate} AND b.date <= {endDate} 
   return DISTINCT(thm.title) as thing, count(b) as amount 
   order by amount desc  LIMIT 50"""
).on("item" -> name, "startDate" -> startDate, "endDate" -> endDate, "exclusions" -> exclusions)
val resultList = cypherQuery.apply()
```

Why does this query work in the neo4j console but not work in scala using anormcypher?

Answer (score 1):

The `exclusions` parameter should be an array of strings, not a single string that gets embedded in an array. Try this:

```
val exclusions: Array[String] = Array("item1", "item2")
val name = "aName"
val startDate = "1443657600000"
val endDate = "1443657700000"
val cypherQuery = Cypher("""MATCH (c:Item)-[:INCLUDES_TERM]-(t:Term),(b:Box)-[:CONTAINS_TERM]-(t), 
   (b)-[r:IS_ABOUT_THING]-(thm:Thing) 
   where c.name = {item} 
   AND NOT (thm.title IN {exclusions}) 
   AND b.date >= {startDate} AND b.date <= {endDate} 
   return DISTINCT(thm.title) as thing, count(b) as amount 
   order by amount desc  LIMIT 50"""
).on("item" -> name, "startDate" -> startDate, "endDate" -> endDate, "exclusions" -> exclusions)
val resultList = cypherQuery.apply()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it throws the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported Neo4j type: [Ljava.lang.String;@703f29b0]. It appears to be calling .toString on the array and passing that to the cypher query.